# Writing a Function that will Keep Track of Button Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I'm trying to display on a button how many times a user has clicked the button. I wanted to do this without writing out a separate function for each button, as I plan to have many buttons.

```
<button class="itemButton"> Button A <span class="itemCount"> 0 </span> </button>
<button class="itemButton"> Button B <span class="itemCount"> 0 </span> </button>
<button class="itemButton"> Button C <span class="itemCount"> 0 </span> </button>
```

My approach was to try to access the span via the itemCount class on the button, increment the timesClicked property of that button in the "items" object, and then set the text of the span to that value.

```
var items = {
    "Button A": {
        timesClicked: 0
    }
    "Button B": {
        timesClicked: 0
    }
    "Button C": {
        timesClicked: 0
    }
}

$('.itemButton').click(function () {
    var itemName = $(this).text();
    items.itemName.timesClicked++;
    $(this).children(".itemCount") = items.itemName.timesClicked;

});
```

I've read some other questions about tracking button clicks but didn't find any that addressed this situation exactly. I spent a while sifting through the Jquery API and played with a number of different functions, so it's very possible that I'm taking a completely incorrect approach. Thank you for any guidance you can offer.

Comment: You might want to use the `.data()` prototype for storing this information on each individual button.

Comment: `items.itemName.timesClicked` should be `items[itemName].timesClicked`

Comment: @sroes why?  is there a functional difference between the two?  (I'm asking out of ignorance here, not nitpickery) EDIT:  never mind.  totally missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can use `data` attributes to identify your buttons more reliably:

```
<button class="itemButton" data-button="A">
    Button A 
    <span class="itemCount">0</span> 
</button>
<button class="itemButton" data-button="B">
    Button B 
    <span class="itemCount">0</span> 
</button>
<button class="itemButton" data-button="C">
    Button C 
    <span class="itemCount">0</span> 
</button>
```

Then you can use this to identify each item in the object. Note, you need to use an array index notation when accessing an object property using a variable, and also your object syntax was incorrect.

```
var items = {
    "A": { timesClicked: 0 },
    "B": { timesClicked: 0 },
    "C": { timesClicked: 0 }
}
$('.itemButton').click(function () {
    var button = $(this).data('button');
    items[button].timesClicked++;
    $(this).children(".itemCount").text(items[button].timesClicked);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6uftQ/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the property of an object by a variable, you should use brackets:

```
items[itemName].timesClicked
```

In your case you're actually looking for a property called `itemName` of the `items` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Demo:[In Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/m8afr/)

Firstly, you missed comma separator in your `items` - variable.
Also, the text in the buttons is your entered text + count of clicks (but keys in `items` - variable are only text before count, so `items.itemText` will be always undefined. The best way is to add IDs of the buttons and add these IDs as keys in `items` - variable.
Check my example it's very simple and works as you want.

HTML:

```
<button class="itemButton" id="btnA"> Button A <span class="itemCount"> 0 </span>     </button>
<button class="itemButton" id="btnB"> Button B <span class="itemCount"> 0 </span> </button>
<button class="itemButton" id="btnC"> Button C <span class="itemCount"> 0 </span> </button>
```

Javascript:

```
var items = {
 "btnA": {
    timesClicked: 0
 },
 "btnB": {
    timesClicked: 0
 },
 "btnC": {
     timesClicked: 0
 },
};

$('.itemButton').click(function () {
    var itemId = this.id;
    if(items[itemId] != undefined){
    items[itemId].timesClicked++;
    $(this).children(".itemCount").html(items[itemId].timesClicked);
    }
});
```

Hope this help you.